# when implementing a list with C, I'm trying to remove the first element and preserves the remainder of the list

Tags: c

so I have it like this

```
struct NODE{ 

    int val;

    struct NODE *next; 

} *list_head;
```

3 nodes have been correctly inserted into the list. And I want to remove the first

I tried

```
list_head->next = list_head;
```

and

```
list_head->next = list_head->next->next;
```

am I doing it wrong? or they are right and that's not the problem?

Answer (score 3):

That would be:

```
// NODE previous_head = list_head;
list_head = list_head->next;
// free(previous_head);
```

Basically, you replace the head with the second node. De-allocate resources if needed.

Comment: Mind @Rom Grk's warning: you should 1) take a copy of list_head before deallocating, 2) replace `list_head` and 3) free the copy